# Angular 4 HTTP Get Request with authorization header 401

Tags: angular, http, angular-httpclient

I'm trying to get data from an API that requires an Authorization header. It works great on Postman and Node but when I try to use it in Angular it just returns a 401. Can someone find an error in my request? Spent long time trying but couldn't find a solution.

This is my `data.service.ts`

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpHeaders } from '@angular/common/http';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';

@Injectable()
export class DataService{

constructor(private authHttp: HttpClient) {}

  getData()
  {
    return this.authHttp.get('<<API URL>>', {
      headers:
          new HttpHeaders()
          .append('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET,PUT,POST,DELETE,PATCH,OPTIONS') 
          .append('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', 'http://localhost:4200')
          .append('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', "Access-Control-Allow-Headers, Access-Control-Allow-Origin, Access-Control-Request-Method")
          .append('Authorization', "<<my token>>")
          , responseType:'text'})
          .subscribe(data => data);


  }

}
```

This is the call I'm making to the service to retrieve that data, but the subscribe method is returning an error

> Property 'subscribe' does not exist on type 'Subscription'. Did you
>   mean 'unsubscribe'?

This is my data.component.ts (cut some lines for brevity)

```
constructor(private dt: DataService) { }

this.dt.getData().subscribe(result => {

      if (result){

        console.log(result);        

      }
      else  {

        console.log('no result');       

      }
    });
```

Appreciated!

Comment: If it works in Postman, then you have a proper reference to look at and find the differences. Utilize the developer tools of the browser you use to inspect the request. Inspect the request in Postman. Spot the differences and fix them.

Comment: I appreciate your time but I have already told I spent some hours looking for a solution. If it was to get an answer like that, I wouldn't come and post a question here, with all due respect.

Comment: But there is nothing we can do with this description and this code. Numbers of things could wrong, based on what your API endpoint is like. 401 is not a global error, it's a very valid response from the server which you can use however you like. There's nothing wrong with your _code_, something is wrong in the way you want it to work with your specific API. We don't know what is it exactly that you _want_ to make, nor we know what your API looks like. Hence there is not much we can to help you with your question written like this.

Comment: Cool, so my question is answered. **Can someone find an error in my request?** If you say no, then I'll have to look for other issue. I wanted to know why I couldn't make a successful request in Angular but in Node I could. I think it could be helpful to some people to understand, as myself. Headed over the Angular docs for HTTPClient and tried everything but nothing worked. I appreciate your answer. If I find a solution I will post here.

Comment: editing the question to try to make it better.

Comment: Your four first headers are useless in this request, they are supposed to be set in the backend. You need to check how to set the authorization header. Should it perhaps be `basic`, `bearer`? As pointed out by others, we cannot know based on the code you are presenting :)

Answer (score 0):

In `getData()` it doesn't look like your are actually returning an `Observable` as you are executing `subscribe()` within that method. Instead try removing the subscribe and using the `map()` operator to return an `Observable` so that when you call `getData()` in `data.component.ts` you can `subscribe()` to the observable stream:

DataService:

```
getData() {
  return this.authHttp.get('<<API URL>>', {
    headers:
      new HttpHeaders()
        .append('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET,PUT,POST,DELETE,PATCH,OPTIONS')
        .append('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', 'http://localhost:4200')
        .append('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', "Access-Control-Allow-Headers, Access-Control-Allow-Origin, Access-Control-Request-Method")
        .append('Authorization', "<<my token>>")
    , responseType: 'text'
  })
  .map(data => data);
}
```

data.component.ts:

```
this.dt.getData().subscribe(result => { // do something with the result });
```

Instead of `map()` you can also utilize [typechecking of the response](https://angular.io/guide/http#typechecking-the-response) to specify the data return type and effectively make `map()` unnecessary unless you need additional processing of the data before getting to `data.component.ts`:

```
interface SomeModel {
   foo: string;
   bar: number;
   foobar: string[];
}

getData() {
  return this.authHttp.get<SomeModel>('<<API URL>>', {
    headers:
      new HttpHeaders()
        .append('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET,PUT,POST,DELETE,PATCH,OPTIONS')
        .append('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', 'http://localhost:4200')
        .append('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', "Access-Control-Allow-Headers, Access-Control-Allow-Origin, Access-Control-Request-Method")
        .append('Authorization', "<<my token>>")
    , responseType: 'text'
  });
}
```

Hopefully that helps!

Comment: `.map(data => data)` is pretty useless.

Comment: It could probably be removed. I was just wanting to show the critical difference in operators to ensure that `subscribe()` can be executed in `data.component.ts` in this example as `subscribe()` in `getData()` would not return an `Observable`.

Comment: Thanks for that. I have found this issue with the .map instead of .subscribe and was coming to edit the question when I found your answer. hahaha but anyways it doesn't work. Highly appreciated man.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is a (useless) `.subscribe` call in your service. It seems like you're misunderstanding not only how observables work, but also what should happen in `subscribe method`.

## Observables in a nutshell

An Observable is an object which tracks events through time; also called **a stream**. When you call `.get` method of `HttpClient`, you're creating an observable. Think of observables as arrays through time (instead of arrays through space in the memory of a computer).

This is all great, but this stream is useless unless you can read the values which it emits. This is done by **subscribing** to the stream. You subscribe by using the method `.subscribe`. The argument of this method is a function that will be executed every time that a value is observed.

## Your case

You've made a mistake of subscribing in the service. Moreover, you've made a mistake of doing nothing in your subscription.

Instead of subscribing, your service should just return the observable.

```
// in the service

getData() {
  return this.authHttp.get(example.com, headers)
}
```

Then, in your component, you should subscribe to the observable returned from your service.

```
// in the component

public data: any

ngOnInit() {
  this.service.getData().subscribe(data => {
     // once data arrives, this function will be called.
     // "data" will be data returned from your server,
     // so we can store it permanently in a property of the class
     this.fetchedData = data
  })
}
```

You can present your data in your template now (or do whatever you want with it).

Comment: Thanks man! Very well explained! So subscribing in the service is wrong? I have a working situation where my service uses subscribe in a post method then I have another subscribe in the component. That's useless, then? BTW your code didn't work. =/

Comment: Well, it's not a complete code. It's more of a pseudo-sketch for you to build upon and to illustrate the point. Subscribe in the service is not _wrong_, but usually it doesn't make much sense. You want to define the way to get the data in service, not actually get it there. When your component requests data from the server, that's when the data should be fetched. And since it's an async operation, you want to be able to perform on that operation ("materialized" through an observable using RxJS).